# Ubuntu 16.04: App title bars dont change with theme

Tags: unity, themes

Fresh installation of Ubuntu, installed a couple of themes all of which worked nice. When I restarted my system, themes had gone and some fonts, those for folde etc seems to have changed. Some times themes change, some times not and when they change the title bar + top bar dont obey it.

[Titlebar uses Ambience](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhp4v.png)